# Scanning on Ubuntu Server 10.04 LTS?

Tags: ubuntu, hp, printer

Fellow SF Linux users, I have a question for you.

I'm currently trying to set up scanning with a HP LaserJet 3330, but I'm having a tough time.  I was wondering how I can get Ubuntu Server 10.04 LTS to scan from it and then e-mail users without having to connect it via JetDirect.

How would I be able to do this?  If it is not possible, how could I simply scan to a file that I could then transfer to clients connected to the server?

As always, I appreciate the help SFers!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to allow network scanning, you can setup `saned` for network scanning and enable the network backend on the clients.

Answer (score 0):

Why *poll* the scan? You have to "click" at the server side or the client side to initiate a scan. This sound stupid.

As you already have physical access to the scanner (someone has to put the original paper on it) you should *push* instead. Press some buttons there to initiate the scan and delivery. If this doesn't work then you have a really bad scanner.

Nobody wants to walk to the scanner, put paper on it, walk back to the client to "click" and then walk back to the scanner to remove the paper. And having a client sitting beside the scanner just for scanning, is more expensive than having a network attached scanner.

Comment: So how do I set this up?

Comment: @Addikt In my (German) manual of the HP 3300 it is described on page 70. Just read.

Comment: It says to use the HP LaserJet Director software, but I'm running a Linux Server.  I cannot run this software, especially not the GUI components, can I?  I see the TWAIN compliant software, but I tried running SANE and I still can't get it to detect the scanner.

Comment: Mine says you need it to _configure_ the scanner. Not to run it. And **forget** the idea that you need a server for that!